# VNC4Server/vncserver – always use desktop number 1 after starting of the vnc server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, vnc, vnc-server

I am using vncserver on a Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server machine to connect remotely and perform administrative tasks. I do not automatically start VNC. I first connect over SSH and call "vncserver -geometry 1024x800 &" to start it.

However normally vncserver always created desktop 1. Only if I had forgotten about a already running desktop it used 2 or 3 for the second session. But as soon as I killed all processes it started clean at desktop 1 again.

Now since I did some changes in startup by running multiple sessions for testing at a time and also after I changed the hostname of the server it always keeps starting with desktop 2 meanwhile 3. While 1 and 2 is definitively not running. I also removed all logs in my vnc home dir of previous sessions.

Well I'm wondering why and out of what reason it keeps increasing the desktop number sometimes. Also I would like to get it back to desktop 1 and fix it somehow. So that I can easily save the server Ip (IP:1) in my Remote-Profile without the need of changing it from time to time because vnsserver starts from an higher number.

Any ideas why it won't take desktop 1 any more?

:(
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vncserver will take the first available port from 5901 and onwards.  There can be a few reasons why this does not work, like the port already being taken for something else.  Or that vncserver is actually still running. Check out the file specified as log file for a clue.

You can check whether there still are vncserver processes running with:

```
vncserver -list
```

Without more information it's difficult to answer your question to the fullest.  The various vnc implementations also behaves differently.

You can try to force it to open on display :1 by specifying it on the command line

```
vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x800
```

Comment: Thank you :) your tip helped me to solve the problem.
A few days ago I changed the hostname of my computer. Since this change the old session hostname.pid did'nt get deleted after killing the session. New .pid files where created with the new desktop. Now vncserver -kill did not perform the kill correctly since it can't find the right .pid file out of the reason that it tried to find it with the new host name.

Well I also tried to delete all .pid and .log files in the vnc dir of any previous sessions, but the error remained the same. vnc -kill did not perform right. Solution killall Xvnc4

Comment: After  killall Xvnc4 I was able to create desktop 1 again. I just did not think that they still could run somehow since a Vnc connection to desktop 1 was not possible and kill told me that there is nothing running.

But as soon as a I tried to bind it the way you wrote before it told me that there is actually a desktop 1 running … :D